# Enforce restriction on viewmodels using protocols- AssociatedType/conditional-conformance/swift

Tags: ios, swift, associated-types

```
protocol Identifiable {
  var id: String { get }
}
struct ModelA: Identifiable {
  var id: String
}
struct ModelB: Identifiable {
  var id: String
}
protocol ViewModelable {
  associatedtype model: Identifiable
}
struct ViewModelA: ViewModelable {
  typealias model = ModelA
}
class ViewA: UIView {
  var viewModel: ViewModelA
}
struct ViewModelB: ViewModelable {
 typealias model = ModelB
}
class ViewB: UIView {
  var viewModel: ViewModelB
}
class CustomListView: UIView {
  var viewModels<T: ViewModelable>: [T]?
  var viewmodels:[ViewModelable]
}
```

I need to enforce a rule on the models which my viewmodel will hold.  But the syntax in View1 is throwing a compilation error. (Protocol 'ViewModelable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements). So is there any other way i can enforce this?

My use case:

Custom List View is kind of container view which will have a tableview and render the views (of viewmodelA and viewmodelB)

Comment: For the last part about (A & B), I have provided an update.

Comment: Why do you even need the protocol ViewModelable? You could just have two arrays declare to hold ViewModelA and ViewModelB objects respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce it during type definition.

```
class View1<T: ViewModelable>: UIView {
  var viewmodels: [T] = []
}
```

Many standard APIs do this.

```
Array<Element>
Dictionary<Key: Hashable etc.
```

---

#### UPDATE

For accessing your properties through all these protocols back to `id`, you can do this.

```
protocol ViewModelable {
  associatedtype Model: Identifiable
  var model: Model { get }
}
struct ViewModelA: ViewModelable {
  typealias Model = ModelA
  var model: Model
}
struct ViewModelB: ViewModelable {
  typealias Model = ModelB
  var model: Model
}

class View1<T: ViewModelable>: UIView {
  var viewModels: [T] = []
  
  func doSomething() {
      let firstModelID = viewModels.first?.model.id
  }
}
```

---

#### UPDATE 2

> Custom List View is kind of container view which will have a tableview and render the views (of viewmodelA and viewmodelB)

```
class CustomListView1<A: ViewModelable, B: ViewModelable>: UIView {
    var viewModelAs: [A] = []
    var viewModelBs: [B] = []
}

/// You can go one step further as well
class CustomListView2<A: ViewModelable, B: ViewModelable>: UIView 
where A.Model == ModelA, B.Model == ModelB {
    var viewModelAs: [A] = []
    var viewModelBs: [B] = []
}
```

---

#### UPDATE 3

> There are 5+ viewmodels and all of it are rendered in a tableview, so it cannot be held in separate arrays.

```
class View2: UIView {
    enum ViewModel {
        case viewModelA(ViewModelA)
        case viewModelB(ViewModelB)
        // Add as many variants as you want
        
        var model: Identifiable {
            switch self {
            case .viewModelA(let vma): return vma.model
            case .viewModelB(let vmb): return vmb.model
            }
        }
    }
    
    var viewModels: [ViewModel] = []
    
    func doSomething() {
        let firstModelID = viewModels.first?.model.id
    }

}
```

Comment: Inside View1, viewmodels.first.id is not compilable? The main reason i am going through this route is to access protocol properties of model inside view directly. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: `ViewModelable` doesn't expose anything called an `id`. Instead you can try doing `class View1<T: Identifiable>`

Comment: viewModels.first?.model.id gives compilation error

Comment: See the last EDIT

Comment: View1 is kind of ListView, where all the different components are rendered with help of their viewmodels. If i go with this syntax, while creating an instance of View1 i need to provide either ViewModelA or ViewModelB. But in my use case view1 should use both ViewModelA and ViewModelB and render the list view. So i think i cannot use associatedType itself for this use case. Is my understanding right?

Comment: I have edited my question to include more details

Comment: There are 5+ viewmodels and all of it are rendered in a tableview, so it cannot be held in separate arrays.

Comment: @vivin See **UPDATE 3**